# How to get and replace text inside double curly braces in CodeMirror

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I want to create an input where users can write plain text only, but where I can get part of that text and replace it with some HTML.

So, for example, I want to convert a text like `Lorem Ipsum {{dolor}}` to `Lorem Ipsum <some html with data from JS object>`

I have an object with some data.

```
var data = {
    dolor: {
        icon: 'https://placehold.it/16x16/',
        text: 'Dolor text'
    }
}
```

I want to use that to get the custom text and image, so 
`{{dolor}}` should convert to something like

```
<span class="image">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/16x16/">
    Dolor text
</span>
```

[image]

My approach was to use CodeMirror, define a new mode and detect the curly braces, but now I don't know how to get the content between those braces and I don't know how to modify the outputted HTML (as CodeMirror only adds a `cm-NameOfMode` CSS class to the text).

**This is what I have**

```js
var data = {
 dolor: {
  icon: 'https://placehold.it/16x16/',
  text: 'Dolor text'
 }
}

CodeMirror.defineMode( 'uoVariable', function( config, parserConfig ){
 var uoVariable = {
  token: function( stream, state ){
   var character;

   // console.log( state.inString );

   if ( stream.match( '{{' ) ){
    while ( ( character = stream.next() ) != null ){
     if ( character == '}' && stream.next() == '}' ){
      stream.eat( '}' );
      return 'uoVariable';
     }
    }
   }

   while ( stream.next() != null && ! stream.match( '{{', false ) ){}

   return null;
  }
 };

 return CodeMirror.overlayMode( CodeMirror.getMode( config, parserConfig.backdrop ), uoVariable );
});

$(document).ready(function(){

 // Do for each one
 let form__variable_cd_mirror = document.getElementById( 'form-variable__cd-text' ),
  form__variable_cd   = document.getElementById( 'form-variable__cd' );

 let editor = CodeMirror( form__variable_cd, {
  mode: 'uoVariable',
  value: form__variable_cd_mirror.innerText,
  lineWrapping: true,
  scrollbarStyle: null,
  extraKeys: {
   Tab: function( cm ){
    return false;
   },
  },
 }).on( 'beforeChange', function( cm, changeObj ){
  // Typed new line
  var typedNewLine = changeObj.origin == '+input' && typeof changeObj.text == 'object' && changeObj.text.join('') == '';
  
  if ( typedNewLine ){
   return changeObj.cancel();
  }

  // Pasted new line
  var pastedNewLine = changeObj.origin == 'paste' && typeof changeObj.text == 'object' && changeObj.text.length > 1;
  
  if ( pastedNewLine ) {
   var newText = changeObj.text.join(' ');
   return changeObj.update( null, null, [ newText ] );
  }

  return null;
 });
});
```

```css
body {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

/* New CSS */

#form-variable__cd .CodeMirror {
 padding: 8px 12px;
 transition: all 150ms ease-in-out;
 border-radius: 3px;
 border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 outline: none;

 height: auto;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: inherit !important;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

 margin-top: 10px;
}

#form-variable__cd .cm-uoVariable {
 background: #4f4f4f;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 2px 5px;
 border-radius: 3px;

 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/codemirror/5.38.0/addon/mode/overlay.js"></script>

<div id="form-variable__cd-text" style="display: none">Lorem ipsum {{dolor}}</div>
<div id="form-variable__cd"></div>
```

So... any ideas about how can I archive this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I am not a user of CodeMirror, but I already worked with templates in HTML.

Here is an approach:

1. flag all your elements that contain templates (to avoid full scan of your DOM)
2. match all `{{key}}` with keys in your `data` object to generate HTML
3. replace `innerHTML` directly in your templates, or into separate elements (if you want to regenerate from templates later)

Here is how you could do it in a simple way:

```js
var data = {
    dolor: {
        icon: 'https://placehold.it/16x16/',
        text: 'Dolor text'
    },
    lorem: {
        text: 'Lorem text'
    }
};

function getHtmlFromData(dataitem) {
    var html = '';
    if ('icon' in dataitem)
        // Image data type
        html += '<span class="image">' +
        '<img src="' + dataitem.icon + '">' +
        dataitem.text +
        '</span>';
    else
        // Text data type
        html += '<span class="text">' +
        dataitem.text +
        '</span>';
    return html;
}

setTimeout(
    function () {
        var templates = document.getElementsByClassName("template");
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(templates, function (template) {
            for (var key in data) {
                template.innerHTML = template.innerHTML.replace(
                    new RegExp('{{'+key+'}}', 'g'),
                    getHtmlFromData(data[key])
                );
            }
        });
    },
    1000
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="index.jsx"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="template">
      {{lorem}} Ipsum {{dolor}}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My limitation with this approach is that I don't know how to emulate the text cursor of an input with it. I mean, what I have to create is an input (actually something that looks like one) where strings like {{variable}} are converted to HTML in real time. If you have some time check by snippet and write something between double curly braces.

Comment: This must be feasible by calling the function to replace {{variable}} upon `onchange` event on the element and reposition the cursor with `setSelectionRange`. I'll give it a try later, if you don't succeed before me :-)

Comment: @nanilab: I'm getting into CodeMirror. It seems you can do it with their APIs too, with a combo of `doc.setSelections`/`doc.replaceSelections`. I can help you write it (e.g. get array<{anchor, head}>) if you give me a start in your current code.

Comment: Settimeout is used for waiting that the dom finishes loading? What if the dom needs 2000 ms to finish loading?

Comment: The template class reduces the dom scanning considerably. I wanted to replace `Array.prototype.foreach.call(callback)` with a more general approach (`templates.foreach (callback)`), but it just does not work.